# Instantiate a java static inner class from a scala object

Tags: scala

Per the title, this seems like it should be a standard operation, but googling so far has not yielded any results for me. Suppose I have a java class like the following:

```
public class Outer {
  public static class Inner {
    int x;
    Inner(int x) {
      this.x = x;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, suppose I have a scala object like the following:

```
object Blah {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val v = new Outer.Inner(4) // doesn't work
  }
}
```

Instead of compiling as expected, I receive a "type Inner is not a member of Outer" error.
Is there a way to make the above code work as expected?

Comment: May help you: http://www.iulidragos.org/?p=166

Comment: I think the actual name of the inner class would be "Outer$Inner".

Comment: @Mik378, thanks, but that link seems to only discuss non-static inner classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your example and seems to be correct.

If you still have problems try this:

```
object Blah {

  import correct_package.Outer.Inner

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val v = new Inner(4)
  }
}
```